# Unable to log in to network Profile with Google

Tags: bug, login, openid, google-openid

I was trying to add a new Google profile into my Network Profile earlier, and somehow I am now in a state where while I am logged into my StackOverflow profile, when I go to Network Profile, I cannot log in. When I click Google as the provider and choose my original Google profile, I get the following error:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again
```

Curiously enough, if I try to insert an image to the question editor (I guess through imgur), I'm getting the same error.

If I try logging in using the new Google profile, I am redirected to `https://stackexchange.com/#` while still **not** logged in.

Anyone knows what the issue might be?

Comment: I have similar issue right now.